# Xcode - output (array) in *.html file possible?

Tags: iphone, html, arrays, import, textlabel

Is it possible to implement a Xcode array to a *.html file?

The *.html is a local file in my app. The output is a normal UiWebView.

```
<Doctype>
<html>
some text [myXcodeArray] some text
</html>
```

I would like to save a TextInput in Xcode. This array should be the output in the *.html - Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

You need to be a bit more explicit about what you're trying to accomplish here. So you have an array in objective-c and you're trying to dump the content of that array into an HTML file that resides within your app?

If that's the case, just simply iterate through your array and dump the elements to the file.
Try using [KissXML](https://github.com/robbiehanson/KissXML) to generate the XML as needed. If you need to parse the HTML have a look at Ben Reeves [HTML Parser](https://github.com/zootreeves/Objective-C-HMTL-Parser).

Comment: Hi. Yes I want to save an array in objective-c and show this array in myOutlet in my local html file. Thats what I want. The array should be a userInput (Text) .  You say "simply" :-) - Do you mean that I only have to #import the h/m file and find the right method to insert the array between the text? That sounds to simple.

Comment: How can I do that? **just simply iterate through your array and dump the elements to the file**